# How to send get request without content-type by HttpURLConnection?

Tags: java, get, httpurlconnection, content-type

How to send get request without content-type by HttpURLConnection? That means, there is no content-type in the request header.

I found the content-type is **application/json** as default( I don't invoke the

```
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", contentType);
```

).

However, I want there is **no content-type** in the get request.

I use the code to get the contentType of the HttpURLConnection:

```
System.out.println("contentType:" + conn.getContentType());
```

Comment: @Robert In fact, I have tried. Even through NOT call the setRequestProperty("Content-Type",...), the conn.getContentType() is still application/json. So i said, the content-type is application/json as default.